# What is the point of adding a few years of probation to a death sentence?

Tags: death, sentencing, china

I [read](http://www.china.org.cn/china/2015-01/08/content_34499215.htm) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111233432/http://www.china.org.cn/china/2015-01/08/content_34499215.htm)):

> A total of 44 Japanese drug-related criminals were arrested by China in 2014, 33 of which have been given corresponding sentences, five people were executed, and six were **given death sentence with two years' probation**.

What is the point of adding a few years of probation to a death sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a traditional Chinese sentence which in practice is similar to a suspended sentence:

> Mainland Chinese courts hand down the sentence of "death sentence with
> two years' probation" (Chinese: 死缓; pinyin: sǐ huǎn) as frequently as,
> or more often than, they do actual death sentences. This unique
> sentence is used to emphasize the seriousness of the crime and the
> mercy of the court, and has a centuries-old history in Chinese
> jurisprudence. It is almost always reduced to life or 10 to 15 years
> imprisonment if no new crime is intentionally committed during the two
> year probationary period.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_China